# convert Map<id,string> to list<Order.Product> in test class

Tags: unit-test, list, map

I have a method return type of map which I need to convert to `list<Order.Product>`.Here Order is main class and ProductOrder is inner class which has variables.

I have assigned the map to list in below way in test class but I am getting error as Illegal assignment from `Map<Id,String> to List<Order.ProductOrder>`

```
    List<Order.ProductOrder> ordList = OrderService.build(oIds);
```

Here  OrderService classname and build method name which has return type Map.
How to resolve this issue

Comment: If you're doing this in a test class, can you refer to the production class which is doing this work as well to see how the conversion is being performed there?

Answer (score 0):

In general, to convert maps to lists, you would use the map's values method:

```
Map<String, Integer> integersByString = new Map<String, Integer>{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};
List<Integers> integers = integersByString.values();
```

If you want the keys, you need to get the key set:

```
Set<String> keys = integersByString.keySet();
```

now you can convert those to a list:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>(keys);
```

But in your case these won't work since your map contains other types.
You probably need to change the returntype of your build() method.